# Custom shortcode for custom fields with Prefix in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, custom-fields, prefix

I am trying to create a custom shordcode for all of my custom options fields that show up on the front end.
For each custom field i am using a custom prefix 'myprefix'.

Now if i add following shortcode it works fine:

```
[myfield field='myprefix-enable-logo']
```

```
function My_Custom_Shortcodes( $atts ) {
  return get_option($atts['field]');
}
add_shortcode( 'myfield', 'My_Custom_Shortcodes' );
```

But what i want is following structure of shortcode and the prefix is predefined in the function:

```
[myfield field='enable-logo']
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by getting the slug of the attribute of the custom field. then added the custom prefix to it in get_option like following:

```
function My_Custom_Shortcodes( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'field' => 'The slug',
    ), $atts );

  $mcf_slug = "{$a['field']}";
  return get_option('myprefix-' . $mcf_slug);

}
add_shortcode( 'myfield', 'My_Custom_Shortcodes' );
```